# What does can't assign to function call mean (python)

Tags: python

I have recently started learning Python, and I have been assigned the task of creating a function that averages grades in a dictionary.

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}


def average(grades):
    total = 0
    grades.sum() = total
    total.float() = total
    total = total / len(grades)
    return total
```

However, when the function is executed, I receive the error, "Can't assign to function call" What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: It means you can't assign to something like `grades.sum()`.  What do you intend `grades.sum() = total` to do?

Comment: I need to have a summation of the list `"grades"` so I can divide them by the `len(grades)` to get an average.

Comment: IMHO, it's not a typo, it's a fundamental misunderstanding of Python syntax. But I guess that still makes it off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you want to pass a list of grades to your `average()` function.

You have the syntax a bit mixed up in `grades.sum() = total` and `total.float() = total`

You (probably) want something like this:

```
def average(grades):
    total = sum(grades)
    return float(total) / len(grades)
```

And you'd call that function like this:

```
avg = average(alice["homework"])
```

`total = sum(grades)` says calculate the sum of the values in `grades` and store the result in a variable named `total`. The function call `sum(grades)` asks a question, and in Python (like most other programming languages) we write the question on the *right* side of the `=` sign, and the place to put the answer goes on the *left* side of the `=` sign. But your code has that backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a value to the return value of inbuilt function which is not possible..Try this

```
lloyd = {
"name": "Lloyd",
"homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
"quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
"tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
"name": "Alice",
"homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
"quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
"tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
"name": "Tyler",
"homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
"quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
"tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}


def average(grades):
    total = 0
    total = grades.sum()
    total = total.float()
    total = total / len(grades)
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
grades.sum() = total
```

You'd rather do that:

```
total = grades.sum()
```

If you want to dig deeper, here is an **[explanation of the whys and hows](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7304/why-is-english-written-and-read-left-to-right)**.

Comment: Presumably, `grades` is a `list`, and `list`s do _not_ have a `.sum()` method.

Comment: @PM2Ring Presumably, but we can't tell. Perhaps it's a `class` and it has a `sum` method.

Comment: But good spot anyway :)